# Primefaces dataTable in composite component and rowUnselect event

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

### Implementation and Purpose:

I implemented a composite component with a primefaces p:dataTable in it. I also added p:ajax listeners to the table for rowSelect and rowUnselect events whose listeners can be defined by the actual page using the composite component.

### Error situation:

For the rowSelect event and its listener this definition works just fine. In the case a row is unselected the unselect listener is called, however, an exception is thrown indicating that the composite component cannot be resolved in the using page by the EL expression (see the log) which is actually used in the composite component to dynamically lookup the passed listener. And it sounds totally correct to me that this cannot work. The exception's log entry is declared as a warning but the the jsf processing cycle is broken since the update definitions are not executed.

### Question:

Am I missing something in my definition or is the primefaces p:ajax implementation doing something which is not intended? Why am I experiencing this behaviour for the primefaces unselectRow event but not for the selectRow event?

My composite component is:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="selectListener" method-signature="void f()" />
    <composite:attribute name="selectUpdate" />
    <composite:attribute name="unselectListener" method-signature="void f()" />
    <composite:attribute name="unselectUpdate" />
  </composite:interface>

  <composite:implementation>
    <p:dataTable id="abnormalityTable" var="abnormality" value="#{abnormalityTableView.model}" lazy="true"
      paginator="true" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" selection="#{abnormalityTableView.selectedRow}"
      selectionMode="single"
      paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">

      <c:if test="#{!empty cc.getValueExpression('selectListener')}">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{cc.attrs.selectListener}" update="#{cc.attrs.selectUpdate}" />
      </c:if>
      <c:if test="#{!empty cc.getValueExpression('unselectListener')}">
        <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{cc.attrs.unselectListener}" update="#{cc.attrs.unselectUpdate}" />
      </c:if>

      <p:column headerText="#{docText['abnormality.name']}" filterBy="#{name}">
        <h:outputText value="some dummy output" />
      </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
  </composite:implementation>
```

And the stacktrace from the log is:

```
16:59:40,868 WARNUNG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8443-2) Unable to resolve composite component from using page using EL expression '#{cc.attrs.unselectListener}': javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to resolve composite component from using page using EL expression '#{cc.attrs.unselectListener}'
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:444) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:44) [primefaces-3.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.event.UnselectEvent.processListener(UnselectEvent.java:40) [primefaces-3.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:760) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1071) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:126) [prettyfaces-core-3.3.2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:112) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118) [prettyfaces-core-3.3.2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:380) [shiro-core-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
```

Comment: I am using primefaces 3.5-SNAPSHOT